# if not this or this then in lambda python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I am rounding values in a pandas df but I want to catch values which cannot be rounded, i.e. nans, strings etc.

The example below works fine and correctly catches nans:

`df = df.applymap(lambda x: int(round(float(x))) if not isnan(x) else x)`

but how do I add the "-" to this code.

My failed attempt:

`df = df.applymap(lambda x: int(round(float(x))) if not isnan(x) if not "-" else x)`

Comment: Could it be that 'if not "-"' should be something like 'if not x < 0'?

Comment: still get this: TypeError: ('a float is required'

Comment: Ohh ... ok, so you need a type check, somethinig like: 'if not isinstance(x, str)' which would filter out any strings.

Comment: Could you add a small input sample and the corresponding expected output? It seems to me, that this can be solved using [to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html)

Comment: works now, changed it to 'if not isinstance(x, unicode)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a sequence of `or` logic tests should do the trick for you.

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: int(round(float(x))) if not (isinstance(x, str) or math.isnan(x) or x<0) else x)
```

First, this code will check if x is a string. If it isn't, it will check if it's `nan`. If it isn't, it will check if the value is negative (I believe this last part can be removed). If any of those statements returns `True`, the program immediatly won't round the value. Otherwise, it will.

You can even add more rules to this statement, but you will have to pay attention: the order you insert them will define if the rules work. For example, if I inserted the rules in the order below, the system would return an error when finding a string value:

```
x<0 or math.isnan(x) or isinstance(x, str)
```

This happens because the first attempt to verify the given value would consist in a test to check if it's a negative number. However, this comparison wouldn't work with a string. That's why we first add the rule to check if it's a string before going on.

So when adding rules, I repeat: **be careful with the order you insert them!**